# Mysql Left Join duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables which I want to join together. The 2nd table is tricky and I will try my best to explain this here

Following tables are in question:
1) table1
2) table2

#### Table1

```
+---------+-----------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
| Orderid |   name    |  Sku  | row_total | tax_amount | discount_amount |
+---------+-----------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|     002 | Product1  | Sku1  |       100 | 0.5        | 1.5             |
|     002 | Product2  | Sku2  |       200 | 0.5        | 1               |
|     002 | Product3  | Sku3  |       300 | 0.5        | 0               |
|     002 | Product4  | Sku4  |       400 | 0.5        | 5               |
|     002 | Product5  | Sku5  |       500 | 0.5        | 50              |
|     002 | Product6  | Sku6  |       600 | 0.5        | 0.5             |
|     002 | Product7  | Sku7  |       700 | 0.0        | 10              |
|     002 | Product8  | Sku8  |       800 | 1.5        | 0               |
|     002 | Product9  | Sku9  |       900 | 2          | 2               |
|     002 | Product10 | Sku10 |      1000 | 3          | 30              |
+---------+-----------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
```

#### Table2

```
+----------+--------+------------+
| MOrderid | mowner | mrealorder |
+----------+--------+------------+
|      002 |     95 |    3333333 |
|      002 |    100 |    3333333 |
|      002 |    320 |    3333333 |
|      002 |     95 |    3333333 |
|      002 |    504 |    3333333 |
|      002 |    112 |    3333333 |
|      002 |     95 |    3333333 |
|      002 |     99 |    3333333 |
|      002 |    106 |    3333333 |
|      002 |     11 |    3333333 |
+----------+--------+------------+
```

Here is the query which I am writing to get my desired output, I've tried to display the final result I am looking for.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.Orderid, o.name, o.Sku, o.row_total, o.tax_amount, o.discount_amount, m.mowner
FROM table1 o
JOIN table2 m ON ( o.Orderid = m.Morderid )
```

Here is the result which I get after running it

```
+---------+-----------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------+--------+
| Orderid |   name    |  Sku  | row_total | tax_amount | discount_amount | mowner |
+---------+-----------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------+--------+
|     002 | Product1  | Sku1  |       100 | 0.5        | 1.5             |     95 |
|     002 | Product2  | Sku2  |       200 | 0.5        | 1               |     95 |
|     002 | Product3  | Sku3  |       300 | 0.5        | 0               |     95 |
|     002 | Product4  | Sku4  |       400 | 0.5        | 5               |     95 |
|     002 | Product5  | Sku5  |       500 | 0.5        | 50              |     95 |
|     002 | Product6  | Sku6  |       600 | 0.5        | 0.5             |     95 |
|     002 | Product7  | Sku7  |       700 | 0.0        | 10              |     95 |
|     002 | Product8  | Sku8  |       800 | 1.5        | 0               |     95 |
|     002 | Product9  | Sku9  |       900 | 2          | 2               |     95 |
|     002 | Product10 | Sku10 |      1000 | 3          | 30              |     95 |
|     002 | Product1  | Sku1  |       100 | 0.5        | 1.5             |    100 |
|     002 | Product2  | Sku2  |       200 | 0.5        | 1               |    100 |
|     002 | Product3  | Sku3  |       300 | 0.5        | 0               |    100 |
|     002 | Product4  | Sku4  |       400 | 0.5        | 5               |    100 |
|     002 | Product5  | Sku5  |       500 | 0.5        | 50              |    100 |
|     002 | Product6  | Sku6  |       600 | 0.5        | 0.5             |    100 |
|     002 | Product7  | Sku7  |       700 | 0.0        | 10              |    100 |
|     002 | Product8  | Sku8  |       800 | 1.5        | 0               |    100 |
|     002 | Product9  | Sku9  |       900 | 2          | 2               |    100 |
|     002 | Product10 | Sku10 |      1000 | 3          | 30              |    100 |
|     002 | Product1  | Sku1  |       100 | 0.5        | 1.5             |    320 |
|     002 | Product2  | Sku2  |       200 | 0.5        | 1               |    320 |
|     002 | Product3  | Sku3  |       300 | 0.5        | 0               |    320 |
|     002 | Product4  | Sku4  |       400 | 0.5        | 5               |    320 |
|     002 | Product5  | Sku5  |       500 | 0.5        | 50              |    320 |
|     002 | Product6  | Sku6  |       600 | 0.5        | 0.5             |    320 |
|     002 | Product7  | Sku7  |       700 | 0.0        | 10              |    320 |
|     002 | Product8  | Sku8  |       800 | 1.5        | 0               |    320 |
|     002 | Product9  | Sku9  |       900 | 2          | 2               |    320 |
|     002 | Product10 | Sku10 |      1000 | 3          | 30              |    320 |
+---------+-----------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------+--------+
```

#### My desired Output

```
+---------+-----------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------+--------+
| Orderid |   name    |  Sku  | row_total | tax_amount | discount_amount | mowner |
+---------+-----------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------+--------+
|     002 | Product1  | Sku1  |       100 | 0.5        | 1.5             |    320 |
|     002 | Product2  | Sku2  |       200 | 0.5        | 1               |     95 |
|     002 | Product3  | Sku3  |       300 | 0.5        | 0               |     95 |
|     002 | Product4  | Sku4  |       400 | 0.5        | 5               |    100 |
|     002 | Product5  | Sku5  |       500 | 0.5        | 50              |    106 |
|     002 | Product6  | Sku6  |       600 | 0.5        | 0.5             |    504 |
|     002 | Product7  | Sku7  |       700 | 0.0        | 10              |    112 |
|     002 | Product8  | Sku8  |       800 | 1.5        | 0               |     95 |
|     002 | Product9  | Sku9  |       900 | 2          | 2               |     99 |
|     002 | Product10 | Sku10 |      1000 | 3          | 30              |     11 |
+---------+-----------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------+--------+
```

## PROBLEM

The main issue here is happening with the `mowner` column. It keeps repeating itself for each item until all the `mowner` are completed. Can someone please look into it and try to help me get the desired result which I've shown in this question.

Comment: Please try to explain what the logic is for choosing which `mowner` matches which `name`.

Comment: to archieve your desired result you should use an unique column as comparison, for example, if you add the product name or sku to the second table, and join them by THAT, you should get the desired result.

Comment: I am looking forward to get suggestions on building that logic.

Comment: table 2 is kinda confusing for me, it is the detail of the ORDERID or the PRODUCT?, for what it seems, its the PRODUCT, so it should go joined with name (if thats the logic), i dont know if you understand me, but the current tables wont allow you to get the desired result imo....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK!, it took some time, but if you still want to have two tables, (you could just add the rows mowner and mrealorder to table 1) you need to add a row, in this fiddle you can execute both querys and see the result, your current query is :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT o.Orderid, o.name, o.Sku, o.row_total, o.tax_amount, o.discount_amount, m.mowner
    FROM table1 o
    JOIN table2 m ON ( o.Orderid = m.Morderid )
```

i changed it a bit to this

```
    SELECT DISTINCT o.Orderid, o.name, o.Sku, o.row_total, o.tax_amount, o.discount_amount, m.mowner
    FROM table1 o
    JOIN table2 m ON ( o.Orderid = m.Morderid and o.name = m.Mname)
```

you can see the whole example in this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73bde/3

since mowner result is not the same that you "desire" you would need to explain HOW to get that value, when you do i would glady modify my current answer to add that.

Regards..

Comment: Shocklo, this seems to have worked for me. I have to join few other tables. Around a total of 4 tables will be joined. I will keep you posted how it goes.

Comment: @Muhammad glad i could help, ill be waiting to see how everything turns out.

Comment: I am stuck on one other table with same scenario unfortunately I don't have any other logic I can apply. I will try to post a new question and let you know